# How get comments from cells with Google Sheets api

Tags: google-sheets-api

How i can get comments using Google sheets api?

`fields=sheets/data/rowData/values/note` return only notes

For example it's note
[note](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFUUL.png)
and it's comment
[comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxsgh.png)

So how i can get comments?

Comment: I don't know Google Sheets API, but having used comments on Google Sheets I wonder if they might be attached at a different level than the cell.  I can add a comment to a range, also, so it might be that they are attached at a different point in the document, such as to the sheet itself. When posting questions you should also try to paste your code directly into the question and avoid linking to external sites. You may also want to remove the `java` tag if this is not a language specific question.

Comment: @karora thank you for answer! When i download as excel document, `comments` was formatted as `notes`. Strange

Comment: Your question helped me to write the fields correctly, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can list comments using the Google Drive API. Using the spreadsheet ID you can reference the file in Google Drive too.

To list the comments of your spreadsheet call the [`Comments: list`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/comments/list) endpoint.

```
curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID]/comments?fields=*&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Got comments. I'll mark it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

It's available as the `note` field in [`CellData`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells) which you can get through [`spreadsheets.get`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) with the `includeGridData` parameters set to `true`

Comment: Thank you for answer! I get note `test` in field `note`, but doesn't get comment